# Display fa-icon if image loading fails

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I want to display a fa-icon if the image loading fails. Like in alt attribute text appears if image loading fails instead I want to show a fa-icon, If there is any way using js/jquery etc please share.
Code I'm using:

```
<div class="panel-body text-center" style="background-color:#f99d1c;">
                        <?php if($count>0){
                            echo "<img src='/presenations/$company/$curl/$fileurl' class='img-thumbnail' width='165px' class='img-thumbnail' alt='ERR_RLF'>";
                        }else{
                            echo "<i class='fa fa-video-camera fa-4x' style='color:#FFF;'></i>";
                        }?>
                        </div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are looking for `onerror` attribute for `img` element.

## Here it is:

## UPDATED

**Pure JS Solution**

```js
function imgError(image) {
    image.outerHTML= '<i class="fa fa-video-camera fa-4x"></i>';
    return true;
}
```

```css
.red_block {
  background: red;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<!-- Image element with invalid path so it does not load and onerror gets call -->
<img src="image.png" onerror="imgError(this);"/>

<br>
<!-- Same thing with valid image path so it loads -->
<img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150" onerror="imgError(this);"/>
```

> So what you need to replace here is HTML structure of fonts if you want anything else than this.

Comment: That's What i was looking for !

Comment: Glad that helped you!

Answer (score 0):

According to @divy3993 .You just have to place a loading gif in background.

```js
function imgError(image) {
    image.outerHTML= "<div class='red_block'></div>";
    return true;
}
```

```css
.red_block {
  background: transparent url('http://thinkfuture.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/loading_spinner.gif') center no-repeat;;
  padding: 110px;
}
```

```html
<img src="image.png" onerror="imgError(this);"/>
```